# copiar carpeta node_modules a otro equipo

Tags: javascript

Actualmente estoy haciendo unos proyectos pero no cuento con una laptop y la pc que uso es prestada quisiera saber, si es posible instalar todas las dependencias en la carpeta node_modules como por ejemplo sass o react y luego copiar todo la carpeta del proyecto incluyendo el archivo node_modules y correrla en otro equipo es decir otra pc sin problemas, claro con el mismo sistema operativo. en este caso windows.

Comment: si. node_modules solo es una carpeta donde se bajaron un monton de archivos. no hay nada "instalado" ahi...

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo copiar todos los archivos menos node_modules, y al tenerlo en tu otro equipo ejecutas:

```
$ npm install
```

Comment: No seria de recomendar, es lo que se deberia hacer si se esta trabajando con esto